# On master node: binding to port 8040 java.net.BindException

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have a 2-node cluster(hadoop 2.6.0) with a master(as salve) and 1 slave in etc/hadoop/salve on the master machine. 
After calling

```
start-yarn.sh
```

jps shows

```
:~$ jps
11821 SecondaryNameNode
11114 NameNode
12037 ResourceManager
11432 DataNode
12674 Jps
12363 NodeManager
```

and within a minute the NodeManager is gone with an BindException: Address already in use in the log file(pasted below). The port 8040 is open and used by ResoureManager.

log file on master

```
    2014-12-19 17:21:25,185 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NodeManager metrics system...
2014-12-19 17:21:25,186 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system stopped.
2014-12-19 17:21:25,186 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system shutdown complete.
2014-12-19 17:21:25,186 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:8040] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.getServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.HadoopYarnProtoRPC.getServer(HadoopYarnProtoRPC.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.YarnRPC.getServer(YarnRPC.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.createServer(ResourceLocalizationService.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStart(ResourceLocalizationService.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceStart(ContainerManagerImpl.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:509)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:8040] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.<init>(Server.java:573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.<init>(Server.java:2205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.<init>(RPC.java:931)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server.<init>(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:537)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getServer(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:512)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Builder.build(RPC.java:776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.createServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.getServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:132)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:407)
    ... 21 more
2014-12-19 17:21:25,189 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG
```

dfsreport

```
:~$ hdfs dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 216116072448 (201.27 GB)
Present Capacity: 55109070848 (51.32 GB)
DFS Remaining: 55109021696 (51.32 GB)
DFS Used: 49152 (48 KB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (2):

Name: 192.168.179.3:50010 (slave)
Hostname: xyz
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 83369902080 (77.64 GB)
DFS Used: 24576 (24 KB)
Non DFS Used: 63215587328 (58.87 GB)
DFS Remaining: 20154290176 (18.77 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 24.17%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1



Name: 192.168.179.58:50010 (master)
Hostname: abc
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 132746170368 (123.63 GB)
DFS Used: 24576 (24 KB)
Non DFS Used: 97791414272 (91.08 GB)
DFS Remaining: 34954731520 (32.55 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 26.33%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
```

Comment: Try using `netstat` to discover what is bound to 8040.

Comment: `lsof -i:8040` shows that 8040 is used by `pid:12037` whish  is   Resourcemanager as per logs from jps( As given in the question.)on Master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BindException - Address already in use - This is an indication that port 8040 is busy and is in use by someother process. You could overcome this by changing the default yarn port in file `etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml` as below:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.address</name>
    <value>192.168.179.58:10200</value>
</property>
```

Comment: do I need to change the same on salve machine? as the Nodemanager is up on slave machine.

Comment: Yes wherever your NM is running.

Comment: Still same issue, after adding the given property on yarn-site.xml file.The Nodemanger either active on Master or active on slave. the Nodemanager starts on both slaves but dies on one of the slave with an error  `java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address;`

Comment: Why multiple instances of NM? You just need one instance.

Comment: Correct my understanding, "Client->ResourceManager->NodeManager->App master" on multinode cluster(2 slaves). which means if slaves are two machines then we need a NM on each machine?

Comment: Or is it one NM for a multinode cluster.

Comment: Hi @SMA, are you sure? I see YARN documentation where it shows you need one nodemanager on each slave node in a cluster setting.